# Web Service security header validation on WebLogic

Tags: web-services, weblogic

I have a web service deployed on WebLogic that has a usernameToken security policy. I implemented my own Java password validator (that extends com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.WsitDigestPasswordValidator).

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="DoubleItBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false"/>
            <sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic128/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
            <sc:ValidatorConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
                <sc:Validator name="usernameValidator" classname="service.PasswordValidator"/>
            </sc:ValidatorConfiguration>
            <sp:Wss11/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

My problem is that when i try to invoke my web service using a SOAP message containing the security header, the header is completely ignored, as if the web service has no security attached.

I have tried creating in the WebLogic console a new Web Service Security configuration and reference it in my service's class using the annotation WssConfiguration, but the result is the same.

I have also tried adding a WS-Policy to my WebService ( policy:Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.1-UsernameToken-Digest-DK.xml), and still the same.

Could you please tell how to activate the validation of my SOAP message security header in WebLogic?